# Separar una carpeta de Windows con fotos, en varias subcarpetas por fecha, la cual está incluida en el nombre de cada registro

Tags: r

Tengo una carpeta en mi escritorio Windows la cual contiene cientos de fotos, cada registro de foto está nombrado como " IMG_20210406_175814" la cual incluye la fecha en la cual fue tomada.
Necesito crear varias subcarpetas que agrupen cada registro por la fecha en que fueron tomadas. Por ejemplo las del año 2020, 2021, 2022 y 2023.
Tengo muy poco manejo de R, pero entiendo que primero debería convertir esta carpeta, que llamo "Fotos", en un objeto manejable en R, quizá un Data.Frame, para luego generar el código que me permita separar cada archivo por una fecha determinada y crear con ellas un nuevo Data.Frame que llamaré "Fotos 2020".
Agradeceré enormemente cualquier ayuda brindada

Comment: Saludos Juan, bienvenido a SOes, lecturas recomendadas para que puedas aprovachar al máximo tu estadía en la plataforma: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 + https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask + https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour En este último enlace encuentras tu primera medalla, verás cómo funciona el sitio pues este sitio **no** es un grupo de fb u otra red social, ni un foro convencional; hay lineamientos para seguir, investiga un poco, intenta hacer algo. Preguntas sin intentos tienen menor chance de obtener respuesta. Que tengas un buen día :D

Comment: Lo siento fredyfx, claramente me equivoqué de sitio con mi simple pregunta. Son demasiado "Elevados" para mi. Hasta nunca.

Comment: Dudo mucho que seamos demasiado "elevados", si lo fuéramos, no estaríamos aquí. Por otro lado, gracias por leer el recorrido, espero te vaya bien :)